# How to search for a value that IS NOT equal to the speciefied value?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB and I need a query to check of a value is NOT a certain value, I know how to search for a value like this:

```
db.getCollection('ships').find({"name": "MY BOAT"})
```

**So lets say I need a query that finds the entries where name is not "MY BOAT"**

I allready checked out the `$NOT` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

But don't understand how to apply it.

Comment: Did you see the `$ne` operator?

Comment: No have not tried that, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('ships').find( { name: { $ne: "MY BOAT" } } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

```
follow the above url for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with the `$ne` operator, so the query becomes:

```
db.getCollection('ships').find({"name": {$ne: "MY BOAT"}})
```

The credits for this answer go to [@JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk)